# Describing the set of inner automorphisms for an extraspecial group of order $p^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A non-abelian $p$-group $P$ is called *special* if
$$
 P' = \Phi(P) = Z(P)
$$
and these groups are elementary abelian. It is called *extra special* if these groups are cyclic of order $p$. The group $\Phi(P)$ denotes the Frattini subgroup, i.e. the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $P$.

Now I want to show:

> If $P$ is an extra special $p$-group of order $p^3$, then
>   $$
>  \mbox{Inn} P = \{ \alpha \in \mbox{Aut}(P) : (xZ(P))^{\alpha} = xZ(P) \mbox{ for all } x \in P \}.
> $$

**My Attempt**: If $\varphi_a \in \mbox{Inn} P$, then 
$(xZ(P))^{\varphi_a} = (xZ(P))^a = x^a Z(P)$, and this equals $xZ(P)$ if and only if $[x,a] = x^{-1}x^a \in Z(P)$, which holds as $Z(P)$ equals the commutator subgroup, hence $(xZ(P))^{\varphi_a} = xZ(P)$. For the other direction, if $Z(P) = P' = \langle [u,v] \rangle$ and $(xZ(P))^{\alpha} = xZ(P)$ for each $x \in P$, then for each $x \in P$
$$
 x^{-1}x^{\alpha} = [u,v]^i
$$
for some $i \in \{1,\ldots, p\}$. If I now somehow could show that $x^{-1}x^{\alpha} = [x,a]$ for some fixed $a \in P$ for each $x \in P$, then I would be done. But I have no idea how to derive this from the above condition, I only see that $x^{-1}x^{\alpha}$ can assume at most $p$ distinct values $[u,v]^i$ ($i = 1,\ldots, p$), and hence that some $[u,v]^i$ has at least $p^2$ values of $x$ which are mapped onto it. I do not know if this is enough to show that $\alpha$ is an inner isomorphism and how to do this. So I am asking for any help from you!

Comment: If you downvote I would be glad for a short comment as to why you think my question is inappropriate or what you think is wrong with it!

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but there are mistakes in your definition of the first extraspecial group. You need to include relations saying that $[x,y]$ commutes with $x$  and $y$ . Also, these descriptions are only correct for odd $p$. For $p=2$,  the quaternion group $Q_8$ has both $x$ and $y$ of order $4$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing out! I deleted the presentations, as this could also be found easily elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve the problem is to observe that $|{\rm Inn}\,P| = p^2$ , but there are at most $p^2$ automorphisms $\alpha$ satisfying the condition in the right hand side of your equality, because $\alpha$ is determined by its action on a generating set of $P$ and, for any $x \in P$, there are at most $p$ possibilities for $x^\alpha$. The same proof works for all extraspecial groups, not just those of order $p^3$.the